# how to handle cron response in google web toolkit, running on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have created a simple google webtoolkit project using the tutorials on google and deployed it on google app engine.
I have created a test button for the rpc service action on the client side in the onModuleLoad():

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Listen for mouse events on the test Cron button.
    cronTestButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        calculateStockData();
    }
    });
}
```

The calculateStockData() function will create the service and execute the calculateStockData(callback) function on the server which will return a simple StockData object.

```
private void calculateStockData() {
    // Initialize the service proxy.
    if (stockPriceSvc == null) {
        stockPriceSvc = GWT.create(StockDataService.class);
    }

    // Set up the callback object.
    AsyncCallback<StockData> callback = new AsyncCallback<StockData>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

        }

        public void onSuccess(StockData result) {
            updateTable(result);
        }
    };
    // Make the call to the stock price service.
    stockPriceSvc.calculateStockData(callback);
}
```

So in my web.xml file I have a service defined:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>stockDataServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.stockdata.StockDataServiceImpl
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>stockDataServiceImpl</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/stockwatcher/stockPrices</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I execute the code using the cron test button I receive the StockData object as a response from the service when its successfull in onSuccess, and I update the gwt flexTable  in the updateTable() function.

The problem is that I want to perform this same update action on the gwt widget in response to the calculateStockData() service function when it is executed via a cron job.

So the cron job is executing the calculateStockData() function correctly after I added the following to my cron.xml :

```
<cron>
    <url>/stockwatcher/stockPrices</url>
    <description>Get stock prices every 5 minutes</description>
    <schedule>every 5 minutes synchronized</schedule>
</cron>
```

But I do not know how to set up a listener to handle the response from the cron job execution on the client side.
Could anyone help with this? Let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AppEngine, you can use the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) to push data from the server to the clients (using [gwt-gae-channel](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-channel/) on your client code to connect to the channel).

Otherwise (and oversimplifying), you have to store your data on the server and have clients regularly poll for new data.